# Using `read` in bash script from pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

Bash can run scripts from pipeline. A minimal example would be:

```
> echo "echo hello world" | bash
hello world
```

This is handy if you wants to run a script downloaded from `curl` or `wget`.

But apparently, you cannot use `read` in this kind of script execution. For example,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo 'input: '
read HELLO
echo hello: $HELLO
```

If you simply run the above script from a bash script file, you'd get to input the value of `$HELLO`. and the `echo hello: $HELLO` will print the result.

If you feed the script in the manner we talked about previously:

```bsh
> echo "echo 'input: '; read HELLO; echo hello: $HELLO" | bash
input: 
hello:
```

You won't get the interaction at all. And `$HELLO` remains empty. I've also tried to add `-i` option in bash, and it didn't work.

Is there any way we can use `read` in the pipelined script? How? Or, if we can't, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piping data to a process's stdin without causing EOF afterward](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103885/piping-data-to-a-processs-stdin-without-causing-eof-afterward)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` will "interact" with the user via the stdin (where it will read stuff from) and stderr (where it will print its `-p` prompt, if any).

If the stdin is the *script*, `read` will get its stuff from it, causing it to skip a line:

```
$ echo '
read foo
what the -)(*$;?
echo "$foo"
' | bash
what the -)(*$;?
```

This is hardly a good practice, and will not work in all shells. Also notice that when piping scripts via stdin, `bash` will have to read them byte-by-byte.

In your example, your whole script was a single line, so the `read` builtin will just get EOF and not set any variables.

If you want `read` to always read from the controlling tty, then redirect it explicitly:

```
read var </dev/tty
```

This should be used sparingly, too. Nobody will appreciate you if they have to use `expect(1)` in order to instrument your script.